# Netlogo: Combine similar turtles and combinatorical pair creation

Tags: list, netlogo

Two questions:
1. How can I group the numbers of turtles that have some specific variables that are in my specified criteria. For example create turtles that Id1 is "1".
Desired output would be list of number of turtles that contain similar values.
2. If I have gotten the list of turtles that contain similar ID-s I would like to get a combination off all available turtles. In python (as it is only language that I feel familiral in) I would use:

```
turtle_list = ["1","2","4","5","6","7"]

def create_pairs(source):
        result = []
        for p1 in range(len(source)):
                for p2 in range(p1+1,len(source)):
                        result.append([source[p1],source[p2]])
        return result

pairings = create_pairs(turtle_list)
print("%d pairings" % len(pairings))
for pair in pairings:
        print(pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way.  For more efficiency, if you really need it, implement the pairing algorithm you describe above.

```
turtles-own [id]

to setup
  ca
  let _ids range 5
  crt 100 [set id one-of _ids]
end

to pairup [_id]
  let _ts (turtles with [id = _id])
  ask _ts [
    create-links-with other _ts
  ]
end

to test
  setup
  pairup 0
end
```